# Rewrite all URL to index.php except whitelist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In `.htaccess` I've wrote this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|test|css|js|files|wiki|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But I've got two problems:

1. http://example.com/ajax/index.php don't convert to http://example.com/index.php/ajax/index.php
2. I can see listing of any of whitelisted directories, how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|test|css|js|files|wiki|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Options All -Indexes
```

- Last line should fix listings, using request uri in condition should fix rewrite.